# How to make clamping circuit to clamp exactly at 3.3 volts

Tags: adc, input, diode-clamp

I am building a circuit that attenuates the signal and sends it to 3.3V ADC, so I need to limit max voltage to 3.3V. After testing out some circuits for clamping the voltage(various schottky or zener diodes configurations) I found out that they are not really as precise, for example I managed to get 3.5 or 3.7 Volts when applying for example 5 V sine at the input. I suppose for short duration 3.8V is not so bad for ADC, but ultimately it still not a good thing, especially if I leave it like so for a while.

Is there a way to make it more or less precise?
I tried to find some advice on the net and textbooks, but seems like most of the time people don't really care about precise clamping voltage or if they do they promote to use some special input protection ICs (which are good thing, but I just don't have one around at the moment)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRx33R.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: If you have a circuit which already attenuates, why not just attenuate it to a max of 3.3V.

Comment: It is just voltage divider with offset, i.e. it attenuates the signal 10 times. So if I apply 10V sine it will output 1V sine, but if for example I apply 40V it will give 4V sine. I mean attenuator does not intrinsically limit the voltage to pre-defined value.

Comment: Usually clamping with shottky is fine. Why do you need anything better? What ADC datasheet says about absolute maximum rating?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason that people don't care about the precise clamping voltage is because in most cases, it isn't important enough to take special precautions. Unless you have some really unusual circuit configuration (not revealed) a Schottky diode to ground and another one to the ADC supply voltage should suffice in 99+% of cases.  Most microcontrollers have built-in clamping for signals of moderate impedance.

You may be chasing after problems that don't actually exist.

Comment: So if understand correctly that the external diodes + internal ADC protection in the end would give what I want(3.3 clamping)? Oh, that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: To emphasize Richard Crowley's point, it's not necessary to clamp the voltage at *exactly* 3.3V. The inputs of most IC's can take a few hundred mV above the power rail without damage, as long as there is some form of current limiting.

Answer (score 3):

Drive the ADC with an op-amp that includes voltage limiting such as the OPA698M.
http://www.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/ds/symlink/opa698m.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I am using external BAT 43 Schottky-diodes to clamp inputs beyond the 3V3 and 0V rails.

Several ADC [single-ended] ADC-inputs are monitoring LiPo cell voltages and thus require differing potential-dividing arrangements. It is a low-voltage application nowhere exceeding ~+40V.

Potential-divider resistances are chosen such that should 40V be falsely applied causing input-clamping to occur, then no more than a 1mA will flow through that clamp-diode. This helps to hold the clamp-/forward-voltage of the diode to  around 300mV and dissipation at worse would ~40mW.

The BAT 43 diodes are chosen because of its low-leakage currents. These currents will "pull" the ADC level (even if only slightly) due to the IxR through the divider's components. The diode-cascade will cause the 3V3 diode's leakage current to "offset" the 0V and help reduce their influence at the nodal point on the ADC line.