# Current loop measurements with MCU

Tags: 4-20ma

I want to measure currents in range between 4-20 mA. Could you tell me whether this circuit is good for this operation. I'm using an ADC 3.3V in a microcontroller (thus, I receive voltages in range between 0.52 - 2.6V).

[image]

Comment: Adding 10K series to ADC input can protect from over voltage.

Comment: What is your 4-20mA sensor? You must prevent the ADC line from reaching it's max voltage (which is 3.3 or 5V or something like that)

Answer (score 2):

The schematic looks ok, a clamping diode might be useful to protect the input:

[image]
Source: [How to make clamping circuit to clamp exactly at 3.3 volts](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/234308/how-to-make-clamping-circuit-to-clamp-exactly-at-3-3-volts)

The resistor is there to limit current into the diodes.

Answer (score 1):

Your circuit looks OK. At 20 mA you will have 20 mA x 130 ohm = 2.6 V on your ADC input which is within range. You could even increase R1 to increase the sensitivity of your circuit.

You do need to be very careful that R1 can't become disconnected as the current source output will then rise to 24 V DC and destroy your microcontroller.

Comment: If your ADC (or MCU with built in ADC) is expensive enough, it might be worth adding some protection circuitry in case R1 does get removed somehow. Since the source is current-limited, a Zener diode would be an obvious choice--though not, perhaps, the best.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally okay. I would suggest a low-pass analog filter with some series impedance as @Sunny suggests.

Although you can do some filtering in the analog domain, if there are spikes that exceed the ADCs linear range or there are frequency components higher than half your sample rate you cannot remove the disturbances later, so an anti-aliasing filter can be quite useful.

Under some conditions R1 can be destroyed if the input is connected incorrectly. It's possible to add protection but it would add a bit of complexity.